# Model larger than screen until click on screen Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

**PROPBLEM:**
I have a model that is populated by a database call onInit. once it is populated it grows bigger than the screen until I click on the screen then it resizes to correct size.

**My Thought** 
I was thinking that it would be an issue with changeDectorRef, but I have tried a few things.

1. call `changeDectorRef.detectChanges()` afterViewInit
2. call `changeDectorRef.detectChanges()` after populate the data

**Question:**
Is there a way that I can have this dectect changes after model is open and data is populated?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing about the modal implementation, but have you tried mat-dialog from material.angular.io ? It works.

You could also try cdRef.markForCheck() after populating the data. It marks the entire ancestor tree for checking instead of only the component's tree whose detector's detectChanges you call.

Another good idea and may be better practice actually:

Don't load data in the modal-hosted component. Make it a dumb component, ie. load data outside and pass it to the modal component all ready for presentation.

Comment: thank you, i have not. Do you have a link for the documentation?

Comment: I am not loading data into modal. modal is just hosting a different component.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the component hosted in the modal :) Could you load the data before opening a modal?

Comment: Calling markForCheck is still a perfectly fine solution too, I think it should fix this as the modal itself isn't a child of the component hosted in it.

Comment: I will look into this. thank you and post my findings.